# How to solve these differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find that W which corresponds to X = 0.6.
It's given that at

1)W= $0$, at X =$0$

2)y=1, at X = 0

\begin{align*}
\frac{dX}{dW} &= 0.024  y(\frac{1-X}{1-0.1478X}) \\
\frac{dy}{dW} &= \frac{-0.0083 (1-0.1478X) }{y}
\end{align*}

I divided both the equation and used separation of variables technique to integrate the equations
\begin{equation}
 \frac{dX}{dy } = \frac{0.024  y(\frac{1-X}{1-0.1478X}) }{ \frac{-0.0083 (1-0.1478X) }{y}}
\end{equation}
Integrating y from 1 -> y  and x from 0 -> 0.6, I got y = 0.52334. Is there any way to find the value of corresponding W?
I know one approach might be to find y as a function of x like this and then replace it and solve for W but the expression has a $y^3$ which would make the integration impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(1-bx)^2}{1-x}\,dx=-ay^2\,dy$$

can be integrated analytically, in the form $y=f(x)$.

Then

$$dw=\frac c{f(x)}\frac{1-bx}{1-x}dx.$$

requires just an antiderivative, but an analytical solution is highly improbable.